# Array of templated class instances

Tags: d

I've been writing a command line arguments parser for an application. These can be of three types: boolean, string, or numeric. A given argument will expect a given type, so there is no guesswork here.

I chose to represent an argument as a class, called `Arg`. The same switch can appear multiple times, so I wish keep track of identities, hence the class.

The thing is, although there are multiple types at play, the processing is always more or less the same. In order to avoid writing code, I thought I could template the `Arg` class, essentially like this:

```
class Arg(T)
{
    public:
        T value;

        this(T defaultValue)
        {
            value=defaultValue;
        }
}
```

My problem is that I would ideally just stack those in a dynamic array, but I would have to know the type of them first : I can't exactly declare an array as `Arg!whatever[] myArray`.

I can obviously use a base type, something like `Object[] array`. The thing is, I'd then have to cast each array item before using it. I could write a helper function for this, but it hardly seems idiomatic. I would, however, keep all the type-related pain in a single function. (this is what I'd do without external advice)

I suppose I could also maintain separate arrays. But this isn't too convenient: I need to think about the various numeric types, and if I were to add new argument types, I'd have to add new arrays.

I also tried using `std.variant`, but didn't find them too convenient for my purposes. I might have been using them wrong, but I found myself having to write the exact same functions with multiple signatures, of the form:

```
Algebraic!(string, bool, int) value;        

this(string defaultValue) { this.value=defaultValue; }
this(  bool defaultValue) { this.value=defaultValue; }
this(   int defaultValue) { this.value=defaultValue; }
```

Which hardly seems like working smart.

What would be the correct way to proceed ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: FWIW, here is how I implemented an argument parser in D: https://blog.thecybershadow.net/2014/08/05/ae-utils-funopt/

Comment: Is there a common interface between them at all?

Comment: You can create a base type like `ArgBase`, that has the shared functionality that you need, and make the `Arg` template class inherit from it.  If you need to use functionality of some args that other do not share then your only option is to cast--this is not a language limitation, it is just not possible while being statically typed.

Comment: I did try this, but it comes down to just using Object, because I'm using the (templated) `value` field all the time. So I'd end up casting my `ArgBase` to `Arg(T)` all the time nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

What exactly is wrong with using std.variant? Instead of writing all those different overloads, you can simply use templated functions:

```
class Arg
{
    private Algebraic!(string, bool, int) value;

    this(T)(T defaultValue) if (is(T : string) || is(T : bool) || is(T : int))
    {
        this.value = defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does solve one of my big problems with Variants, thanks !

A problem I had (as silly it may seem) is that I couldn't manage to properly display the value. My `Arg` has a `toString(sink, fmt)` method, which itself calls `format("%s", this.value)`, essentially. But I'd get a full representation with type, parameters, etc, when I'd just wanted the value. After spending some time looking for a solution (another format specifier maybe ?) in the documentation, I thought I'd ask on SO.